# Flash AS3 movieclip doesn't stop motiontween and no errors are given

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have the following piece of code:

```
var Note1:MovieClip = mcNote1;

//Init
Note1.stop();
```

The instance name and everything is correct but yet it doesn't stop the movieclip??

Here a short overview of my flash file

[image]

Comment: Can you describe what you expect to happen when you use `stop()`? If you're trying to stop the target from moving along its path in the main timeline, that is not what `stop()` does.

Comment: Well that is exactly what's supposed to happen. I've seen tutorials doing that but here it doesn't work.. How can I make it stop moving from the start and play again when I want it to.

Comment: You can't make just that layer stop moving - `stop()` is used to stop the timeline of the target, not its parent. You could use stop() on its own to stop the main timeline but that would stop the objects on the other layers as well.

Comment: Well at least that works for now, when I hit the button it plays 1 time and the song starts playing, but I want to loop that specific animation how do I do that?

Or perhaps you could take a look at the fla? Its CS4 btw.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a couple things. You could edit your movie clip and insert a Keyframe and add "stop();"  to frame 1 of your movieclip. Or you could try "Note1.gotoAndStop(1);" in your main function.